# How do I insert a non-breaking space with the Android OS Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, nexus-4

At times I insert a non-breaking space (on my Mac) instead of characters in a Last Name field when filling out forms. Is there a way to do this using the default or some other keyboard on my Nexus 4 (4.2.2)?

Comment: It's not possible with the default keyboard. Someone may answer to suggest a keyboard which has this functionality.

Comment: Sounds like a case for [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard). But as I never checked, I cannot tell for sure if it supports this.

Comment: The other difficulty is that the font must support it. It is the case for Droid Sans and Droid Serif, but others font may not implement it.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try with [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard). They offer "compose key" functionality, which can be used for non-breaking space and more:

[image: Hacker's Keyboard]
<sup>Hacker's Keyboard (click image for larger variant)</sup>

See the "circle key" to the right of the space bar? If you long-press it, [according to the FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#What_does_the_Circle_%28or_check_mark%29_key_do?), this activates "compose key mode". They seem to follow the "standard rules" here, so "2x space" should give you a non-breaking space. A list of supported compose sequences can be [found in the code](http://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/source/browse/java/src/org/pocketworkstation/pckeyboard/ComposeSequence.java).

Comment: The source moved to here, but the wiki is not maintained. https://github.com/klausw/hackerskeyboard/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/pocketworkstation/pckeyboard/ComposeSequence.java

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to copy the non-breaking space from somewhere (e.g. [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) has it in the first line between the quotes), or from between the brackets here:

[ ]