# Compose key on external blutooth-connected keyboard

Tags: external-keyboard, input-methods, keyboard-shortcuts, text-input

I have a [Reudo RBK-3000BT VER 1.0](http://www.reudo.co.jp/rboardk/rbk3k/rbk3000bt.html) keyboard connected by Bluetooth to an Android 4.2.2 phone.

Can I use a [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) feature with such a keyboard?
For instance I would type `CAPSLOCK`+`^`+`o` and it would input `ô`.

I know how to install such a [compose key on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey), but no idea for Android.

I would be much more efficient than copy-pasting from [Charmap](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kkinder.charmap&hl=en) every time.

[image]

Comment: I'd like to know, too, for Android 10. In the meantime, we can always work on creating a Termux command-line text editor with a built-in compose key! :)

Answer (score 0):

The nearest I could find to a solution for this question was found at [another Stack Exchange question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43440/how-do-i-insert-a-non-breaking-space-with-the-android-os-keyboard).  According to the "Keyboard layout" subsection of the [User's Guide](https://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/wiki/UsersGuide) for [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) there is a compose key available in their keyboard app.  The thing that I'm not yet able to determine is whether that functionality can then be mapped to a key on an external keyboard.

Unless some other user beats me to a better answer, I will do further research and try to update this answer with any new information I should happen to discover.