# Compose key (multi key) on physical keyboard

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard, input-methods, text-input, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to configure a key, say for example <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, to work as the [Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) on a physical (Bluetooth/USB) keyboard?

I'm used to a Compose key on my desktop computer, and having it on Android would be extremely useful.

This question seems to have been asked almost a decade ago [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66510/compose-key-on-external-blutooth-connected-keyboard), but I believe a lot has changed since then, so I hope that now there might be a way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use an app like [Key Mapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.sds100.keymapper&hl=en&gl=US) to change a specific key' function to make it do what you want.